# Border effect on hover causes problems with checkboxes

Tags: css

I have an `absolute` positioned element that contains list items with checkboxes. When I hover over one of the list items, the `border-bottom` style causes the other checkboxes to move. I've tried to add twice as much bottom padding to the list items to counter this, but it doesn't work. Could someone show me how it's done? Thanks.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/vn6sg1d0/

**html**

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">A tricky filter UI</h1>
<div class="filter-group-container">
  <div class="filter-container filter-list1" data-filter-name="price">
    <h4>Price</h4>
    <ul #id="list1">
      <li><input id="price1" type="checkbox"> <label for="price1">€0-50</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> €50-100</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> €100-200</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> €200-500</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"> €500-1000</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="filter-container filter-list2" data-filter-name="material">
    <h4>Material</h4>
    <ul #id="list2">
      <li><input id="material1" type="checkbox"> <label for="material1">Gold</label></li>
      <li><input id="material2" type="checkbox"> <label for="material2">Silver</label></li>
      <li><input id="material3" type="checkbox"> <label for="material3">Platnum</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="filter-container filter-list3" data-filter-name="gender">
    <h4>Gender</h4>
    <ul #id="list3">
      <li><input id="gender1" type="checkbox"> <label for="gender1">Male</label></li>
      <li><input id="gender2" type="checkbox"> <label for="gender2">Female</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center">Resize me!</p>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Mobile first */

h4 {
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.filter-container > ul.show {
  display: block;
}

.filter-container > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 17px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.filter-container > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .filter-container h4 {
    border-bottom: none;
    /* stop elements moving on hover */
    padding-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .filter-container > ul.show {
    display: flex;
  }
  .filter-container > ul > li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .filter-container > ul > li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  }

  .filter-container h4:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    /* stop elements moving on hover */
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }

  .filter-container label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .filter-group-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .filter-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .filter-container > ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.filter-container').on('click', function() {
  $('.filter-container').children('ul').removeClass('show');
  $(this).children('ul').addClass('show');
});
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you are stating in your jsfiddle, they don't seem to move.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried it on IE, Chrome, and Firefox. I couldn't reproduce it on Firefox, but could reproduce it on the others.

Comment: I am using Firefox only, may be because of that